# Correction of capitalizing of a French address. How to change to uppercase a char in a string after a certain char in regex/java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I try to change Strings like '18 rue D'armenie' or '25 boulevard D'armes' in '18 rue d'Armenie' or '25 boulevard d'Armes'.
How to String.replace this change?

What I do at the moment is like this :

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully(street.trim()).replace(" D'", " d'");
```

I want to add a second replace doing something like this:

```
street.replace("'[a-zA-z]", "'[a-zA-Z]".toUpperCase());
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In a long string, I change the first letter of all words to uppercase. It's just in the case the word is "D'armes", it should be "d'Armes", so I'm trying to add a replace on the string that will make only this change.

Answer (score 2):

You may replace your code with the following one:

```
String s = "25 a-b boulevard d'armes Boulevard D'armes";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(D)(?=')|\\b(?<!-)\\p{L}(?!')").matcher(s); // Or "\\b(?:(D)(?=')|(?<!-)\\p{L}(?!'))" to make it a bit more efficient
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) == null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0).toUpperCase());
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1).toLowerCase());
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => 25 A-b Boulevard d'Armes Boulevard d'Armes
```

See the [Java online demo](http://ideone.com/S1c61n).

**Pattern details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(D)` -  Group 1: an uppercase `D` letter that is...
- `(?=')` - followed with `'`
- `|` - or...
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!-)` -  that is not preceded with `-` (do not capitalize parts of compound words)
- `\\p{L}` - any Unicode letter (you may use `\\p{Ll}` to only match lowercase ones, by the way)
- `(?!')` - and the letter should not be followed with `'`.

**NOTE**: If you want the same behavior for `l'` as for `d'`, and similar, you may add alternatives to Group 1: `\\b(D|L)` or, better, `\\b([DL])` (unless these are *sequences* of letters, when you have to use alternation operator).

Comment: @VladBochenin That part is covered with `WordUtils.capitalizeFully`

Comment: Yes, that is [Dd]' instead of D'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex won't find `d'armes`

Comment: Ok, you want a complete alternative to `WordUtils.capitalizeFully`, let me edit the post then. @Gangnus It does not have to.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Beautiful code, but it will only change incorrect lowcase to uppercase, and not incorrect uppercase to downcase (D' to d')

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Matcher.group doc : Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at **one**.

Comment: @Gangnus Correct. I only have 1 capturing group. That means, I have `.group(0)`, the whole match, and `.group(1)`, the capturing group value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry. It is becoming too complex for me. :-) The next time I will try to provoke you to put all capitalization rules to a regex line. Czech ones :-) - they are really terrible.

Answer (score 0):

`String name  = "stackoverflow"; 
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();`

the value of `name` is `"Stackoverflow"`

[more example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: 1. The change has to be: D'a... to d'A...  2. That construction maybe not the first in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "18 rue D'armenie";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([A-Z])'" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffe`enter code here`r();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toLowerCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // 18 rue d'armenie
```

In the similar way you can make "a" uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate it? You can pass more than one delimiter character to WordUtils.capitalizeFully()

So, a solution to your issue becomes as simple as:

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully(street.trim(), '\'', ' ').replace(" D'", " d'");
```